# jQuery sortable doesn't work correctly with horizontal list if list is empty before init

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

If I add elements to list after I initialize `.sortable` it doesn't work correctly.

See example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NQMPr/1/)

**Sample HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
</div>
<br />
<button class="add-fields">add</button>
```

**Sample JS:**

```
$(".container").sortable({
    containment: 'parent'   
});

$(".container").disableSelection();

$(".add-fields").click(function(){
    $(".container").append("<div>sucke</div>")   
})
```

**Sample CSS:**

```
.container {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.container > div {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 80px;
    background-color: red;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: default;
}
```

---

### UPDATE

I found related issue here http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7498

> because this.floating is only determined in _create, if you start with
>   an empty sortable it is assumed to be vertical.

Comment: Its working fine for me.. I did manually add a <div> with words other than suck.  The div's drag and sort fine.  Perhaps with all the divs with the same name don't make this obvious?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The workaround for that jQueryUI bug is to initialize the sortable with an element inside, then remove it immediately after initialization.

HTML:

```
<div class="container"><div id="test">blah</div>
</div>
<br />
<button class="add-fields">add</button>
```

Javascript:

```
var i = 0;

$(".container").sortable({
    containment: 'parent'   
});
$(".container").disableSelection();
$("#test").remove();

$(".add-fields").click(function(){
    $(".container").append("<div>sucke" + (i++) + "</div>")   
})
```

And a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NQMPr/25/) showing it working.

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine for me.. Try unique names for the category divs...

```
$(".container").sortable({
    containment: 'parent'     
});

$(".container").disableSelection();

$(".add-fields").click(function(){
    $(".container").append("<div>sucke"+Math.round(Math.random()* 100)+"</div>")   
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NQMPr/23/

update.. my bad. in the above example I did have one element inside the container.  When I start it from empty, you are right, the div's don't sort.  Apologies...